# Noun followed by 「っぱだ」

Tags: grammar

I'm currently reading a Japanese children's book, and a character says
    「金色の葉っぱだ」
I'm assuming the 「っぱだ」 is like saying 「たくさん」 or 「いっぱい」, but I don't actually know. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

葉{は}っぱ is a word.  It means leaf!

Comment: Thanks! The author uses 葉 by itself in a previous sentence, which threw me off.

Answer (score 12):

As snailplane says, for practical purposes, just think of 葉っぱ as a word meaning 'leaf'. In colloquial speech 葉っぱ is probably more common than 葉.

I haven't been able to find decisive evidence, but I conjecture that the っぱs occuring in (at least) the below words

> 葉っぱ
>   原っぱ
>   下っ端
>   木端微塵{こっぱみじん}

is the same morpheme, meaning "something unimportant", "edge", "small piece" etc. Maybe someone else can confirm this.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the use of っぱ in this context! Shines some light on the difference in connotation between 葉 and 葉っぱ.